# Java выводит непонятное значение

Tags: java

> ```
> class Calculator {
>   public static void main (String args[]) 
>   throws java.io.IOException {
>   double Euro, Dollar;
>   int Currency; 
>   char ignore;
>   do {
>   System.out.println("Выберите вариант конвертации");
>   System.out.println("1. Евро в Доллары");
>   System.out.println("2. Доллары в Евро");
>   Currency = (char) System.in.read();
>   do {
>       ignore = (char) System.in.read();
>   } while(ignore != '\n');
>   } while (Currency <'1' | Currency >'2');
>       switch (Currency) {
>       case '1':
>       System.out.println ("Введите сумму в Евро ");
>       Euro = (double) System.in.read();
>       double result1 = Euro * 1.5;
>       System.out.println("За " + Euro + " eur" + " Вы получите " + " $"+ result1);
>       break;
>       case '2':
>       System.out.println ("Введите сумму в Евро ");
>       Dollar = (double) System.in.read();
>       double result2 = Dollar * 0.8;
>       System.out.println("За " + "$" + Dollar + " Вы получите " + result2 + "eur");
>       break;
>       }
>   }
> }
> ```

```
В консоли выводится следующее:
Выберите вариант конвертации
1. Евро в Доллары
2. Доллары в Евро
1
Введите сумму в Евро 
2
За 50.0 eur Вы получите  $75.0
```

Почему используется значение 50.0, а не 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

System.in.read() читает байт, а 50 - код символа '2' в ASCII (в десятичной системе). Именно 50 считывается и конвертируется в double, а не число два. Чтобы получить нужное число, нужно из введённого символа отнять '0' (именно символ, а не число 0. Ну или отнять число 48 (код символа '0'). Работает только для ввода от 0 до 9).  Для ввода чисел лучше использовать java.util.Scanner.

Answer (score 0):

просто создай обьект  java.util.Scanner scanner = new  Scanner(); и получи  в переменую Euro = scanner(System.in); вместо Euro = (double) System.in.read();